# Get width of element passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-ref

How do I get the width of Start Adornment passed in InputProps in Material UI Text Field/Input?

```
<TextField {...{
    InputProps: {
      startAdornment:
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          Kg
        </InputAdornment>
    },
}}/>
```

Here is the implementation of TextField

```
<FormControl>
    {label && (
        <InputLabel disabled={disabled} htmlFor={id} {...InputLabelProps}>
            {label}
        </InputLabel>
    )}
    <Input startAdornment={StartAdornment} />
    {helperText && (
        <FormHelperText id={helperTextId} disabled={disabled} {...FormHelperTextProps}>
            {helperText}
        </FormHelperText>
    )}
</FormControl>
```

I am getting startAdornment in InputProps and trying to pass ref to it to get width of it in componentDidMount

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.ref = React.createRef()
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Did mount', this.ref.current.offsetWidth)
}
const StartAdornment = React.cloneElement(this.props.InputProps.startAdornment, {ref: this.ref})
```

I am getting undefined. I do get element in the current property of ref but offsetWidth is undefined. Not sure what is wrong here.